# "Unsubdivide" = Reduce vertices in loops

Tags: modeling

I have several strands of a ponytail shown in the image below (project file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_D-06f6xFGSXIE1dBXc7fFLEpaY4mB2/view?usp=sharing)). I made these by applying Curve modifiers to several Bezier curves. As you can see, each loop in the strands has way too many vertices inside (I must've incorrectly applied Subdivide and gotten myself more points in the loop as well as more loops). What is the safest way to reduce the number of vertices per loop while preserving the overall shape? Decimate and Limited Dissolve seem to get me messy results (e.g. incomplete loops that go, say, 50-75% of the way around), and Unsubdivide gets me a spiky-looking mesh. Thanks!

[image: img]

Comment: You could select a ring, then checker deselect, then select edge loops, then dissolve, as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU but there may be a faster way, could you please share your file so that we can test (share at least a part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots If you still remember this question. I uploaded a test file via Google Drive. I'm running 2.79b. But it does seem like Checker Deselect works well, especially with the n (=2) and skip (=3) options. I'll reprint and accept as answer unless maybe someone knows another way.

Comment: the modifier Decimate > Planar mode seems to work fine as well, it needs a bit of rework though (but with the knife, some joined vertices and some dissolve edges it would be quite fast), also there's an addon called Instant Meshes Remesh that you could try: https://blender-addons.org/instant-meshes-remesh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MoonBoots' comment, Checker Deselect seems to be an effective solution. Ctrl+Alt+RMB over a perpendicular (non-loop) edge; Select -> Checker Deselect; Select -> Edge Loops; and delete edge loops. Under Checker Deselect, the N option determines deselect pattern (e.g. n=2 means -/+ and n=3 means -/-/+ if skip=1), and the Skip option determines number of adjacent edges to be included in that + (e.g. skip=2 means (+/+)/- and skip=3 means (+/+/+)/- if n=2). See video (does not demonstrate use of N and Skip options): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU

Answer (score 1):

As you say the *Checker Deselect* trick works fine to simplify this kind of topology.

In your case the modifier *Decimate (Planar* mode) seems to work fine as well, just find the good *Angle Limit* value, then it needs a bit of rework, but with some joined vertices and dissolved edges it is quite fast.

Also there's an addon called [*Instant Meshes Remesh*](https://blender-addons.org/instant-meshes-remesh/) that you could try.

Here is what I got with *Decimate*:

[image]
[image]
[image]